# Remove similar lines provided by Hough transform

Tags: matlab, opencv, hough-transform

I found with Hough transform more lines but somethings are very similar for my final target.

For example

[image]

In this image I have 5 lines but I really need just 2 lines.

How I can remove the unnecessary lines?

My code is

```
image = cv.Canny(image, 200);

lines = cv.HoughLinesP(image,'Threshold',80,'MinLineLength',100,'MaxLineGap',50);
```

A simple way can be with lines intersecting, but lines can be parallel and very close in certain situations.

Any idea?

Comment: Look for the start and end point of the lines and if for each line they are very close (with tolerance) mark as duplicate

Comment: Might not work here, because of the dark green and light green lines on the left for instance, where the start points are close but the end points are not...

Answer (score 2):

My crude method was

- use canny edge detector
- take the first line from houghlines
- draw black thick line over the original line in houglines inpu
- repeat until you get no output from houghlines

I used it to detect edges of a card, so I took four best lines.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I solved it. First I grouped similar lines based on a threshold for their rho and theta values. Once lines are grouped then I averaged similar lines parameters within each group to create a single representative line.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def unify_lines(lines, rho_threshold=10, theta_threshold=np.pi/180*10):
    # Group lines that are similar based on thresholds
    unified_lines = []
    for line in lines:
        for rho, theta in line:
            if not unified_lines:
                unified_lines.append((rho, theta))
            else:
                matched = False
                for u_rho, u_theta in unified_lines:
                    if abs(u_rho - rho) < rho_threshold and abs(u_theta - theta) < theta_threshold:
                        average_rho = (u_rho + rho) / 2
                        average_theta = (u_theta + theta) / 2
                        unified_lines[unified_lines.index((u_rho, u_theta))] = (average_rho, average_theta)
                        matched = True
                        break
                if not matched:
                    unified_lines.append((rho, theta))
    return np.array([[line] for line in unified_lines], dtype=np.float32)

image = cv2.imread('image.png', 0)
edges = cv2.Canny(image, 50, 150)
lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges, 1, np.pi / 180, 100)

# Unify similar lines
unified_lines = unify_lines(lines)

# Draw the unified lines
for line in unified_lines:
    for rho, theta in line:
        a = np.cos(theta)
        b = np.sin(theta)
        x0 = a * rho
        y0 = b * rho
        x1 = int(x0 + 1000 * (-b))
        y1 = int(y0 + 1000 * (a))
        x2 = int(x0 - 1000 * (-b))
        y2 = int(y0 - 1000 * (a))
        cv2.line(image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 2)

cv2.imshow('Unified Lines', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

You can adjust these thresholds (`rho_threshold` and `theta_threshold`) to your specific use case to get the desired unification of lines.

*[UPDATE] based on Dominique'c comment*:

The new method first groups all the similar lines before it calculates the average and also it assigns weight to the lines based on their length. This way, longer lines, which generally are more reliable indicators of the intended line direction and position, have a greater influence on the final averaged line.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def calculate_length(line):
    rho, theta = line
    return abs(rho)  # Length could be represented by the absolute value of rho

def unify_lines(lines, rho_threshold=10, theta_threshold=np.pi/180*10):
    grouped_lines = []

    # Step 1: Group similar lines
    for line in lines:
        for rho, theta in line:
            matched_group = None
            for group in grouped_lines:
                for u_rho, u_theta in group:
                    if (abs(u_rho - rho) < rho_threshold and abs(u_theta - theta) < theta_threshold) or \
                   (abs(u_rho + rho) < rho_threshold and abs(u_theta - (theta + np.pi)) % (2 * np.pi) < theta_threshold):
                        matched_group = group
                        break
                if matched_group:
                    break
            if matched_group:
                matched_group.append((rho, theta))
            else:
                grouped_lines.append([(rho, theta)])

    # Step 2: Compute weighted average for each group
    unified_lines = []
    for group in grouped_lines:
        total_weight = sum(calculate_length(line) for line in group)
        average_rho = sum(rho * calculate_length((rho, theta)) for rho, theta in group) / total_weight
        average_theta = sum(theta * calculate_length((rho, theta)) for rho, theta in group) / total_weight
        unified_lines.append((average_rho, average_theta))

    return np.array([[line] for line in unified_lines], dtype=np.float32)
```

Comment: This 'unify_lines' method has two drawbacks. 

First of all, it doesn't work for all kind of lines returned by the HoughLines method. For example, take these two lines (rho1,theta1) = (10,0.017453) and (rho2,theta2) = (-10,3.12413). Both lines are very parallel but will not be detected as such.

Secondly, the way of averaging new lines with the average of already handled lines, will make the resulting line shift to one site or the other. The resulting line will not be in the middle of the lines that are used to calculate this single line.

Comment: @DominiqueBijnens check the new method

Answer (score 1):

I would compute the the slope and intercept of the lines and compare them to see if they're *both* within some tolerance you define. The intercept should be described on the same coordinate frame, say with the origin at pixel r,c = (0,0). Identical lines could be merged then. The only failure case I can think of is if you have non-contiguous line segments that would have the same slope and intercept - those would be merged with this approach. But in your image you don't seem to have this issue.

Comment: How would you deal with vertical lines which has inf slope?

Comment: By using polar coordinates!